# How to make a pure white smoke with blender internal render engine (not Cycles)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

```
I use the Quick Smoke to generate smoke.
```

I want white smoke but I can't make pure white smoke with quick smoke , the smoke rendered is grayish.
 I've seen a lot of solutions for cycles renders on You-tube but can't find any for blender internal render engine. 
What's the simplest way to make steam-like pure white smoke with blender render engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make smoke brighter, you need to make color of the smoke  brighter than white. This is howto:

1. In material settings make *reflection* color completely black:

[image]

As you can see, it doesn't affects at all, because this setting rewrites by smoke texture.

2. Next, go to the texture settings and find *reflection color*. Put here something like 5.0. (To set value above the limits click on value and print the number from keyboard)

[image]

This setting mix value 5 times more different than original (black in material settings) color of smoke reflection.

Also, you can set "extra-white" color in smoke color setting:

Select emiter of the smoke (not domain) and in phisics tab find *smoke color* setting

[image]